# How to return a multiple values of one method in template in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How to return a multiple values of one method in template in django

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    
    def total(self):
        x = self.price
        y = self.quantity
        return x, y
```

View :

```
def Invoice(request, pk):
    invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'invoice':invoice}
    return render(request, 'sales/invoice.html', context)
```

How to implement it in Html ? {{ invoice }}

Answer (score 1):

Just pass within view function context all the values to the template you need to render

```
def Invoice(request, pk):
invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id=pk)
total = Invoce.total(x,y)
context = {'invoice':invoice,
           'total': total}
return render(request, 'sales/invoice.html', context)
```

notice that total will be a tuple

Comment: just add the view if you can to show how i can pass within view

Comment: thx, i got a tuple but still same prob again with tuple, how to show it on template !

Comment: if need to show only total, you can return a total from function or if you need to show x, y separately you can send separate values likes so total[0], total[1]